# Universal-Image-Loader not following layout_weight

Tags: android, xml, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader to grab some images and display them in a listview. I am having trouble getting the layout looking right. I want the image to use no more than 25% of the width, and this looks fine in the Graphical Layout view in Eclipse, but when the image is downloaded it is displayed full size which is too large.
I was hoping to avoid using `maxwidth` as I dont know what the full width will be.

This is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:contentDescription="@string/offerImage"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="75"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="tempString"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetailer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Business name"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="99.99 miles"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to look into the scaleType attribute for the ImageView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: try to set `layout_width` value to `0dip` for both `ImageView` and `LinearLayout`

Comment: That did the trick :-) Thank you vmironov. If you want to put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set `layout_width` value to `0dip` for both `ImageView` and `LinearLayout`.
`layout_weight` works only for unused space, so in case image is too large there is no any free space.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with the sizes of ImageViews that are used with UIL too and this helped me:

```
iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file add this in your imageView Tag
Add this

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: fitXY might change the aspect ratio. You should use fitStart if you don't want that to happen